# What does the ^ mean in glob.h?

Tags: c, gcc

What does the '^' mean in this line of code, never seen syntax like this:

`int (^gl_errblk)(const char *, int);`

It's extracted from: https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/Libc/blob/master/include/glob.h, line 68.

Comment: I think it's a typo. It probably should be '&' or '*'. They are physically close on the keyboard

Comment: @Jay if it were `&`, it still would not be valid C.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was tagged as c++. It compiles on g++ 4.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The caret `^` is an operator used to introduce a block variable or a block expression in the clang Block extension:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to define a [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). Basically it's an anonymous function that can be stored and passed by as a variable.